# Create new user in openfire server from android

Tags: java, android, xmpp, openfire

I created my own XMPP server using openfire. When I want to create new user I go to this web page:

[image]

Now I want to build Android app like Spark in which I would able to crate new user.
Can you guide me or direct me to a code snippet for new user creation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for the api its called smack and smackx here is the link.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9731270/good-tutorial-for-using-smack-with-android

Comment: Thanks. Yaxim Project helped me alot.

Comment: that's the problem with giving links instead of a summary of the solution: the links may not exist anymore..

Comment: link not exist anymore

Comment: Link does not exist. Please suggest any other link or solution